# How can I do this excel function universal?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

```
=SUM(A3-C2;A4-C3;A5-C4)
```

How can I do this excel function universal for continuous counting to `A100-C99` without repeating this?

Comment: looks like the last one should be `A100-C99`, or am I wrong?

Comment: @ScottCraner  Yes you are right, thanks.
 But essence of the question is not this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT to iterate the ranges, do the subtraction and sum the outputs.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A3:A100-C2:C99)
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much for quick answer.

Can you help me with one more problem, when the cell is empty SUMPRODUCT response error, how can i fix it ?